# Not getting output from printf to file descriptor C

Tags: c, stdout, file-descriptor

When I run this

```
close( 2 );
fd = open( "newfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600 );
fprintf( stderr, "ERROR\n" );
close( fd );
```

it puts ERROR in newfile.

yet when I run this

```
close( 1 );
fd = open( "newfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600 );
printf( "OUTPUT\n" ); //fprintf( stdout, "OUTPUT\n" );
close( fd );
```

Nothing happens. newfile does get opened in file descriptor 1, but printf doesn't  go through.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I need to call

```
fflush( stdout );
```

to flush buffer 1 out to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're altering the file descriptor out from under the `FILE *`, so it is very natural that weird things would happen.  In general, it's best to just avoid doing that at all, or if you must change the file descriptors,

- Use `open`, `dup2`, `close` instead of `close`, `open` to make it clear you are replacing the file descriptor,
- Do all the changes at the very beginning of the program before you use `stdio`.

If you still want to mess with the file descriptors, here is how you would do it:

```
int fd = open("newfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
if (fd == -1) {
    err(1, "newfile.txt");
}
fflush(stdout);
int r = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
if (r == -1) {
    err(1, "dup2");
}
close(fd);

printf("OUTPUT\n");

// If you really need to close it later...
fflush(stdout);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
```